# Jenkins email extension randomly doesn't send

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I'm using the Jenkins Email Extension to send automated build emails, and about 1/4th of the time, it just simply will not send.

I am getting the expected output of

```
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: emailaddress@example.com anotheremailaddress@example.com
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But it doesn't send the email. This is completely random. No matter what time, what build, or the list of recipients, it just pretends to send the email but doesn't roughly 1/4th of the time.

Are there additional logs for this extension somewhere? Because other than "Sending email to:" in the regular build logs, it doesn't actually give any confirmation that an email was really sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno how you've got the email extension configured, but what I would suggest is spinning up a postfix relay on the server that Jenkins is running on, and configure the email extension to use "localhost". The reason is that then you would get log messages on the server that would show you if Jenkins is actually trying to send the emails or not. It might not be jenkins, it might be something else.

Comment: thanks! Ugh, apparently this is now a question for IT why they're dropping emails...